# jQuery Mobile buttons not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li>Facebook</li>
  <li>Google</li>
  <li>Apple</li>
</ul>

$(document).bind('pagebeforecreate',function(){
  $('form ul li').each(function(){
    $(this).html('<a role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left">'+$(this).text()+'</a>');
  });
});
```

The code above should change the listview into a list of buttons with a plus icon on the left side. However, it isn't working for me. The `<a...></a>` is being inserted correctly, but the icon isn't showing up correctly. This default icon is still being displayed. How can I fix this?

Comment: I still cannot get it to work, so I changed the list into checkboxes. I'll mark your answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the jQuery mobile [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-types.html) a `data-role="button"` attribute is required to style any anchor link as a button.

In your code you have:

```
<a role="button"
```

This is incorrect.
You need to change this to:

```
<a data-role="button"
```

So your whole code will now be:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li>Facebook</li>
  <li>Google</li>
  <li>Apple</li>
</ul>

$(document).bind('pagebeforecreate',function(){
  $('form ul li').each(function(){
    $(this).html('<a data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left">'+$(this).text()+'</a>');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @patrick's reply above, you also need to initialize the button widget after attaching it to the document. Try this,

```
$(document).bind('pageshow',function(){
  $('ul li').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html('<a data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left">'+$this.text()+'</a>');
    var $btn = $('a', $this);
    $btn.button();
  });
});
```